# Increase docker pull timeout

Tags: docker

Sometimes when pulling images I will loose internet for around 3 minutes and then  reconnect, but by then it is too late since `docker pull` usually times out. How can I change this default timeout, to say 10 minutes?

Comment: I didn't find anything which can be done on the user side. I believe this is maintained at the server from where you are pulling the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you, as a client (who is pulling an image), cannot do that much in order to deal with it (at least for now).

The only thing I can suggest is to set the setting: **--max-concurrent-downloads** to **1**. The thing is - Docker daemon, by default, is pulling 3 layers of images at a time (You can observe it in the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) of dockerd). In this case, you are trying to download 3 layers simultaneously, and if the network interruption is encountered, and none of the layers have been downloaded yet, then, tough luck :)

If you set --max-concurrent-downloads to 1 you will instruct dockerd to concentrate network resources it posses in order to pull only one layer. In this case, you most probably will be able to pull it, before this network issue, and, in this case, dockerd will not pull it again - since this layer is already fully present. So, I am sorry, but this is how it is :)